# How to fix a ValueError: None is only supported in the 1st dimension. Tensor 'input_1' has invalid shape '[None, None, None, 3]'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I already built a model in keras then I want to transform it into a tensorflow lite file for andriod deployment.

```
import tensorflow as tf
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(r'/content/drive/My Drive/inceptionv3-transfer-learning__fine_tune.h5') 
model = converter.convert()
file = open( 'model.tflite' , 'wb' )
file.write( model )
```

ValueError: None is only supported in the 1st dimension. Tensor 'input_1' has invalid shape '[None, None, None, 3]'.